# I want to post a string array and a object to server using Loop j

Tags: android, post, loopj

Every time I get the error "**BAD Request**". I'm trying to post data like this json

```
{
"name":"testOne",
"location": "['one','two','three']"
}
```

**Here is my Code**

```
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    String someData="{\"name\":\"testOne\",\"location\": \"['ne','two','three']\"}";
    ByteArrayEntity be = new ByteArrayEntity(someData.toString().getBytes());
    client.post(MainActivity.this, "http://impero-dannyfast.rhcloud.com/api/agents", be, "application/json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Succ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "fail"+statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        });
```

Comment: try `[\"ne\",\"two\",\"three\"]`

Comment: Thanks for your time
But the error still same 

 String someData="{\"name\":\"testOne\",\"location\": \"[\"ne\",\"two\",\"three\"]\"}";

Comment: error 
"Unable to decode data"

Answer (score 0):

check out these tutorials you will get your answer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frltqnSKqiA&list=PLgjt1h_kabFebUn1anGYZ6_Tfkw64Ww12&index=11

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: this is not the way to answer follow community guidelines

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"name":"testOne",
"location": ["one","two","three"]
}
```

try sending like this